# How to make a Linear-LogLog plot in Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to be able to make a plot with the x axis scaled as the log of the log. These types of plots are coming up rather frequently in my ME courses and I've been trying to figure out how to do it, and find that there doesn't seem to be a clean builtin way to do it either in python or in Matlab. Both support semilog (linear vs log(x)) and log-log (log(y) vs log(x)) plots, but I'm not seeing any way to get a semiloglog (linear vs log(log(x))) or log-loglog (log(y) vs log(log(x))) plot.

Anyone have any ideas on this? I could do some conversions by simply applying log(log(xvalues)) to my data, but drawing the grid, tick marks, and labels gets kinda tricky, so I was hoping someone might have already built a library for this.

Comment: Just what kind of data do you have, where taking the logarithm *twice* on one side makes sense?

Comment: one example is plot of absolute viscosity vs temperature for various grades of lubricant. the viscosity ranges from 2 through 10^4. The curves end up being linear on the plot if the viscosity is scaled as loglog.